# WPF combox in datagrid /w LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

despite the search through of stackoverflow I could not help myself with this tiny piece of code.
LINQ to SQL classes basically 2 classes in One to many relationship should be displayed in a datagridview where user could change combobox items

[image]

designer code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDepartments" Margin="10,356,633,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFDBFFDD" ItemsSource="{Binding lstDepartment}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DeptName}" Header="Megnevezés"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Header="Aktív" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Telephely">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.lstLocation}"
                                              DisplayMemberPath="Location1" SelectedValuePath="LocationID" SelectedValue="{Binding LocationID}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

code behind:

```
DataContext = this;
```

lstLocation, lstDepartment filled up, no typos in designer code properties.
Datagrid however not filled what is wrong?

Comment: what about INotifyPropertyChanged implementation! it seems your UI doesn't know that the data has been filled in.